# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' with arrays

Tags: python

it's quite a simple script that I have been having a little problem with
Basically I want the script to print what's in the array except for the integers.

```
array = ["hello", "hey", 1, "sup", 8]
for x in array:
  if x.isdigit():
    continue
  else:
    print(x)
```

I thought maybe using isnumeric.() would solve it but it seems that doesnt work too

and since im quite new it im having trobule figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the type of the value. `1` is not the same as `"1"`; `isdigit` is a method defined by the `str` type, not the `int` type.

```
for x in array:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of a value using `isinstance`. Since `isdigit` is defined for strings only, you are getting an error when the value is an integer(other than a string).

This will print everything except integers.

```
array = ["hello", "hey", 1, "sup", 8, (1,2,3), {1,2,3}]

for x in array:
  if not isinstance(x, int):
    print(x)
```